# Which OpenCV function to use to calibrate on wider than fov chessboard pattern

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, emgucv, camera-calibration

I am looking at documentation here
https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#gab8816c8a176e1d78893b843b3f01557a

And examples here using EmguCV
https://github.com/caulifla/emgucv/blob/master/Calibrate.cs

This, however, uses a fixed size chessboard which is entirely in frame.

And the function `CvInvoke.FindChessboardCorners (grayFrame, patternSize, cornerPoints, CalibCbType.AdaptiveThresh);` requires the horizontal and vertical number of corner points

On my pattern the camera does not see the edges of the chessboard pattern, it is out of FOV on all edges, so I may have a varying number of corner points in the image at any time

Even when I counted the number of corners and set cornerPoints cols to 5 and rows to 4, this function still returns false

Is there a better function for detecting corner points that will work for this calibration example?

I tested `CvInvoke.Find4QuadCornerSubpix(input_image, cornerPoints, new Size(11, 11))` but got an assertion that `n_points >= 0;`

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can construct and use a smaller checkboard, I think it is the simplest solution

Comment: I've been meaning to write code to take any set of corner points and associate them into a square grid that need not have rectangular bounds, i.e. exactly your situation. I haven't gotten around to it.

Comment: your picture is flawed. if it's a screenshot, never ever post screenshots as data. if that is actually what you calculate on, then it's broken. there's a white border, while the actual content is very dark. that can ruin the picture.

Comment: [crosspost](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266159): https://forum.opencv.org/t/calibrating-a-camera-without-a-defined-patternsize/14414

Comment: Why don't place the pattern further away from camera?

Comment: No, ok, no, thank, and no. Pattern and distance from the camera are not changeable. I can easily find corners in this picture with edge detection even at this low contrast. There should be an OpenCV function that already incorporates all of this. I'm asking if there is, if not I will write one.

Comment: OK, Sorry. I don't guess it exists. Implementing your own recognition function will be fastest and easiest way than searching something fits your special condition.